# How do you get a string from inside an actionListener?

Tags: java

I'm having trouble getting the value of a string i have specified inside an action Listener.

I am trying to access UserMessage from this action listener:

```
public class UpdateButtonListener implements ActionListener
{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {    
        String UserMessage;
        UserMessage = MessageTextArea.getText();
        System.out.println("This is your message: " + UserMessage);
    }
}
```

Then access it from this actionListener:

```
private class EncodeButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {   
        //print Message
        System.out.println("Your Message: " + UserMessage);
    }
}
```

They are in different classes in the same package.
I can add the full code if needed.

Thanks

Extra info:
What I want to happen is when I have clicked either the Encode or Decode button.
The action listener running off these buttons to access the action listener on the update button.
The reason that I have the update button is to get the text the user has entered.

Comment: Do you want to access the private field on the method actionPerformed of the UpdateButtonListener, from the actionPerformed of DecodeButtonListener ? Simply you can't unless you declare the variable outermost the two class ... Maybe i don't understand the question, Can you explain better ?

Comment: what you need is basically a reference to MessageTextArea, i guess we need to see the structure to answer properly

Comment: Would it help if posted all the code for both?

Comment: *"Would it help if posted all the code for both?"*  For better help sooner, post one [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I have editied the post as per SSCCE. I just want EncodeButtonListener to access the String value of UserMessage. I have run it outside the actionListener but the only value I get back is the orginal value that I specified when creating the JTextArea.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem with the scope. UserMessage's scope is within actionPerformed.

Try declaring "String UserMessage" outside actionPerformed, and then either you can make it public, in which case in order to access it you should write "UpdateButtonListener.UserMessage", or you make a function that returns the value of UserMessage.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand this: Just use ActionListerns to call methods!

```
public ActionPanel() {
    // Actions
    private final Action aEncode = new AbstractAction("Encode") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
           encodeMessage();
        }
    }
    private final Action aUpdate = new AbstractAction("Update") {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
           setMessage(messageTextArea.getText());
        }
    }

    // Buttons
    private final JButton encodeButton= new JButton(aEncode);
    private final JButton updateButton= new JButton(aUpdate);
    private final JTextArea messageTextArea= new JTextArea();

    private String message;

    public ActionPanel() {
        //Create two rows and one column
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

        //Add border to panel
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Excute"));

        //Add button to panel
        add(encodeButton);
        add(updateButton);
        //add(messageTextArea);
    }

    private void encodeMessage() { 
        System.out.println("Your Message: " + message.getMessage());
    }

    private void setMessage(String message) {
       this.message = message;
       System.out.println("This is your message: " + message);
    }

    public String getMessage() {
       retuen this.message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I changed my code around a bit to suit your but it still isn't picking up the updated Message from the area.

Comment: Sorry, I was on the road. I hope now that the code you need. Like I already told you: Don't use listener to do stuff, they should only call methods from the class (model).